# Match some regular expressions in specific lines and save those lines to an array in bash

Tags: regex, arrays, bash

I need to scan lines of text from a file for specific tags and store whatever is between those tags into an array in bash.  The basic syntax is as follows:

```
<description> "long, multiline text descriptions" </description>
```

Where the text in between gets stored in an array.

Comment: Great!  Did you know that you ask questions here.  If you wanted to announce what you just did, you could do it in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Is this XML? If so, and you want to correctly handle things like comments, character entity escapes, and the like, then you'll want to use a proper XPath engine for this job.

Comment: It isn't XML so much as the return from curl on an RSS feed.

Comment: @IanPanzica, RSS *is* an XML-based format, so the usual caveats all apply. A description could contain `<!-- this is a comment -->` and you'd need to discard it, or `&amp;` instead of an `&`, or `&lt;` in place of a `<`, etc. Format-unaware tools are generally inadequate to this task.

Answer (score 1):

Read file line by line and check regex:

```
arr=()
while read -r s; do
    [[ "$s" =~ "<description>"(.*)"</description>" ]] && arr+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
done < file
```

Comment: Doesn't look to me like this handles the multiline match case.

Comment: Also, the lack of `-r` on the `read` means that backslash-escapes will be processed, which isn't quite literal.

Comment: Thanks and agreed, included `-r` that I skipped earlier.

Comment: I was under the impression that `arr+="$foo"` would append to the first element, as opposed to adding new elements (`arr+=("$foo")`).

Comment: ...indeed, it does just that. -1 for incorrectness.

Comment: Really sorry about making those stupid mistakes in hurry. I should have been more careful to see what I am typing.

Comment: No worries. Assumed that was all there was to it, which is why I waited a few hours before bringing that last one to the point of a downvote. Anyhow, better now -- still has the multiline-support limitation, which is why I haven't placed an upvote here, but that's trickier to fix correctly.

Comment: Actually somehow I missed your previous comment, Yes I totally agree with multiline thing, something which is more suitable for XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

This BASH solution should do the job.

```
arr=()
match=""
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ "<description>"(.*)"</description>" ]]; then
        arr+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
        continue
    elif [[ $line =~ "<description>"(.*) ]]; then
        match+="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
    if [[ $match ]] && [[ $line != *"</description>"* && $line != *"<description>"* ]]; then
        match+=" $line"
    elif [[ $match ]] && [[ $line =~ (.*)"</description>" ]]; then
        match+=" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        arr+=("$match")
        match=""
    fi
done < file
```

Comment: `-d` takes a single character, not a string. This will read until the next `<`.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: LGTM, with all the caveats associated with not using a real XML parser (not being namespace aware, element aware, comment aware, etc etc etc). +1.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation requires xmlstarlet (http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) and assumes that no EOT (end-of-transmission) characters exist within the contents. It has the advantages associated with being based on a real XML parser -- entities are processed, comments ignored, CDATA interpreted literally, etc.

```
descriptions=()
while IFS='' read -r -d $'\x04'; do
  descriptions+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -m -t -v //description -o $'\x04')
```

Answer (score 0):

First a little test script:

```
cat <<EOF >find-tag.sh
#!/bin/bash
# find-tag.sh TARGET XMLFILE
target="$1"
awk "/<description>/   { keep=1; s=\"\" ; next}
     /<\/description>/ { keep=0; if (s ~ /$target/) { print s } ; next}
     {if (keep) { s = s \$0 }}
    " $2
EOF
```

Next a little XML data file, with multi-line entries:

```
cat test.xml
<blah1>
  xxx
</blah1>
<description>
  blah1 blah1 blah1
  blah12 blah12 blah12
</description>
<description>
  blah2 blah2 blah2
  blah2a blah2a blah2a
</description>
<description>
  blah3 blah3 blah3
  blah3b blah3b blah3b
</description>
<description>
  blah4 blah4 blah4
  blah4c blah4c blah4c
</description>
```

Finally, the sample run -- each line of data from `find-tag.sh` is an entry, which is read into the array `data`.  The `data` array is then displayed, one item per line.

```
data=()
# extract tagged entries to a file
./find-tag.sh blah test.xml >/tmp/xml

# read the XML extracts into the 'data' array
readarray -t data </tmp/xml
```

If your bash doesn't support `readarray`, use this instead:

```
while read line ; do data=( "${data[@]}" "$line" ) ; done </tmp/xml
```

Display the data (show the array items):

```
for ((i=0; i<${#data[@]}; i++)) ; do printf "line %d: %s\n" $i "${data[$i]}" ; done
line 0:   blah1 blah1 blah1  blah12 blah12 blah12  blah13 blah13 blah13
line 1:   blah2 blah2 blah2  blah2a blah2a blah2a
line 2:   blah3 blah3 blah3  blah3b blah3b blah3b
line 3:   blah4 blah4 blah4  blah4c blah4c blah4c
```

BTW, you can find some useful array management utilities for bash at https://github.com/aks/bash-lib#list_utils

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using markdown rather than HTML markup -- not only is it more likely to come out correctly, it's also easier to create and edit.

Comment: Do you want that to be `<<EOF` or `<<'EOF'`? In the former case, expansions such as `$1` are interpreted by the shell, and thus don't make it into the file.

Comment: ...also, `data+=( "$line" )` is available in pretty much all of the bash 3.x, so it's safe even when readarray (introduced in 4.0) is unavailable.

Comment: Also, consider passing your script into awk as a non-interpreted literal (single-quotes), and using `awk -v "var=$value" 'script'`; that way, contents in the value can't be interpreted as code.

Comment: Charles, I *do* want to have a bash variable interpreted in the awk script -- see "$target".  Thanks for the other suggestions.

Comment: The point I'm making is that `awk -v "target=$target"` is the safe, best-practices way to get your bash variable into awk. The approach you're using now is a moral (and security) equivalent to `eval`.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the "data+=( 'more stuff' )" suggestion.  I've been bash programming since Brian Fox first started it, and I completely missed that. Happy to learn something new!